# Codeigniter Retrieving Chargify Return parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Chargify with Codeigniter framework. On completion of signup with Chargify, the return URL can be set with parameters. It seems that these parameters can only be returned ?id=123&ref=321. With Codeigniter, how do I grab those return paramenters?

```
http://www.website.com/confirmation?id=3163255&ref=5159c58278a1f
```

Comment: -1 due to lack of efforts.

Comment: @itachi uh, lack of effort my ass. I've been working on this for the past hour. If I am missing something stupid why not enlighten me instead of voting down with no input.

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the parameters from the url? If so, then: `$id  = $_GET['id'];` and `$ref = $_GET['ref'];` should work.

Comment: typically that would work. CodeIgniter strips all GET parameters, so without enabling query strings I can't do it this way. Chargify forces this return and I was looking for a solution to handle this.

Comment: And thanks for actually leaving some constructive feedback Lefters -- @itachi

Comment: Ah, yes - sorry, I forgot about CodeIgniter destroying the `$_GET` array, really annoying! As you don't want to enable query strings, you could try putting this: `parse_str(substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"), 1), $_GET);` before trying to access the `$_GET` array like I suggested above. It should populate the array and allow you to access the parameters. No worries, hopefully this might be a bit more helpful!

Comment: Dude, exactly what I needed. Can you put  into a question so I can hook you up with answer? Thanks @Lefters

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! Sure, I'll do that now, cheers @Bungdaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter, by default, destroys the `$_GET` variable that one would usually use to access the parameters in a URL.

This line will parse the URL and populate the `$_GET` array with the URL's parameters. It's useful for when you want to selectively use the `$_GET` array in a CodeIgniter project, rather than having to enable CodeIgniter's *query strings*, which would be globally and continually active.

```
parse_str(substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"), 1), $_GET);
```

It can then be accessed as you would normally access an array, for example:

```
$id  = $_GET['id'];
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers. Instead link the question that has the answer already in form of a comment or a duplicate-close-vote. Especially as you duplicate [even your own answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15824389/367456). (As you can see duplicate content like these comments are really not helpful for the site in the long run)