# $_GET does not work in Codeigniter 2.1.3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get `ref` value from URI which looks like this `http://localhost/project/?ref=6`
Now I know that `$_GET['ref']` will not work in codeigniter. I tried to enable it by setting `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` but it didn't work.

I read on SO somewhere about using `$this->input->get('ref')` but no luck. Before using it I did loaded `input` library in config.php.

> Note: I want to access this value in model

Added in config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';
```

and commented existing `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` and `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Controller code is:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
        $ref = $this->security->xss_clean($_GET['ref']);
        log_message('info','>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>enter email_invites method::'.$ref);
```

But still I don't get any value and somehow I dont see any of my log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line will parse the URL and populate the `$_GET` array with the URL's parameters:

```
parse_str(substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?"), 1), $_GET);
```

It can then be accessed as you would normally access an array, for example:

```
$ref = $_GET['ref'];
```

You config - *application/config/config.php* - should be set as follows:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

Comment: No luck. Plus I am not seeing my log messages now.

Comment: What are the value(s) of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_GET` after the `parse_str(...` line?

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers. Instead link the question that has the answer already in form of a comment or a duplicate-close-vote.